# Responsive layout, divs with border/background-color, equal space

Tags: css

I would like to create a responsive layout, where inner divs have padding, own background color, and colored border.

The space between inner divs and the space between inner divs and the frame of the container div should be equal.

I can solve this with three layers of divs: container, container of inner divs, inner divs.

```
.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.containers {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}

.item {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 1.5em;
    border: 0.5em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu9m8rn/)

Could I achieve the same result without using an extra layer of divs? Should I maybe look into flexbox?

Comment: (1) Using calc with floats - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/76swyuLf/ (2) Using flex layout - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8end4o6d/

Comment: Hi Abhitalks, I would accept your answer if you post it, since it answers both my questions, and your examples do exactly what was specified.

Comment: There. Added as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I achieve the same result without using an extra layer of divs?

Yes, but with little tricks. Make the paddings and margins in pixels instead of ems to allow for pixel prefect positioning. Also, you will need a little bit of `calc` for width to exclude extra margins and change margins on odd numbered divs to align them neatly. This will provide you with equal spacing between all divs and also between the parent.

**Demo Snippet 1:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.container {
    width: 80%; margin: 8px auto; padding: 16px 16px 0px 16px;
    background-color: pink; overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
    width: calc(50% - 8px); float: left; padding: 16px; 
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.container > div:nth-child(odd) { margin-right: 16px; }

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    .item { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Demo Fiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/76swyuLf/**

---

> Should I maybe look into flexbox?

Yes. A flex layout will make it easier for you. The trick here would be to use `justify-content: space-around;` to allow for equal space in-between the divs and also around them inside the container.

**Demo Snippet 2:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.container {
    width: 80%; margin: 8px auto; padding: 0.5em; background-color: pink; 
    display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
    padding: 1.5em; margin: 0.5em;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: 0.5em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    .item { flex-basis: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo.
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Demo Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8end4o6d/**

---

Answer (score 0):

What about using margin to space the items? You can still use your inner padding and borders. I added a clearfix to your container as well.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvbKdZ

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: pink;
}

.container {
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.container:before, .container:after{
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 48.5%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 1.5em;
    border: 0.5em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .containers {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This way, the space between the container frame and the inner divs don't match than the space between the inner divs.

Also, to have the spacing as em instead of percentage would be nice, since it looks better, and the space probably does not have to change across screen sizes.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. Does @alireza-safian answer help you?

Comment: I am doing my research on calc(), I am not sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Check this(`.container`s are removed)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/vmu9m8rn/2/)

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}
.item {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1.5em;
  margin: 1.5em;
  border: 0.5em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: calc(50% - 4em);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .item {
    width: calc(100% - 4em);
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="containers">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate
    complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate
    complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate
    complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate
    complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate
    complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate
    complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate
    complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be great to find this solution.
Cool!

```css
body {
    background: pink;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.containers {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1.5em 1.5em 0;
}
.item {   
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    border: 0.5em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="containers">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam labores nusquam periculis et, sed ancillae salutatus te, an alia unum decore vim. Quas timeam aeterno ex sea, tale solum usu id. Eu impetus officiis quo. Viderer voluptatibus an eam, possim commune eum ut, te animal suavitate complectitur sed. Numquam veritus delicata duo ea, vix ad dicta meliore.</div>
</div>
```

Click here to find the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/mp3mdya8/)

Comment: This way, there is no space between divs side by side.

Comment: Do you want space between divs side by side? Just remove the left and right padding from the '.containers' div and add margin left and right to the '.item' div.

Comment: You can not mix percentage width with margins using non-percentage units, unless you are using calc().